# Changing Webmatrix IDE color theme

Tags: ide, themes, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I've started working with webmatrix, and I have to admit it works really well.
But the customization is not very intuitive. I've managed to change the code editor color theme to dark, but I can't find a way to change the color theme for the whole IDE.
Google wasn't very helpful on the subject, can it even be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the whole theme of `WebMatrix`, but you can change the theme of the coding window. This can be done by installing the free extension `ColorThemeManager` from there you can download others or create your own theme.

Answer (score 0):

Upon reviewing the choices in "Options", nothing suggests that the look and feel can be altered.

Comment: Aye - currently there is no support for that.